# Spring -servlet.xml beans access

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring normally I access a bean using the method getBean(). Eg:

The AplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www... etc">
       <bean id="MyClass" class="ioc.beans.MyClass" /> 
</beans>
```

The java:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
MyClass cl = applicationContext.getBean("MyClass", MyClass.class);
```

Now I'm working with Spring MVC and beans are created in an xml file with suffix -servlet, and I don't have a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

How I can access my java beans from my controller to work with objects, if do not have getBeans method? (Considering also that this method -the first and foremost feature of Spring at any initiation tutorial- is a bad practice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring within a web application there's no real reason to programmatically get beans like that.

You should use either explicit constructor/setter injection or autowiring.  In the first case, all Spring-managed beans should be defined in your XML (or JavaConfig if you're using it).  In the second, the classes to be autowired should either be declared in your XML/JavaConfig or should be on the component scan path.

Comment: Thanks. Read basing in your reply and now I feel embarrassed of the basics of my question.

Comment: Take a look at the [Spring Petclinic Sample Application](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic) to get a good idea of best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Dependency Injection(Constructor Injection
Setter Injection) can be used.

```
private WildAnimal wild;


@Autowired
  public void setWild(WildAnimal wild) {
    this.wild = wild;
  }
```

In the Xml

```
<bean id="wild" class="com.javapapers.spring.ioc.Wolf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 @Autowired
```

[Annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html)